# TestNG is executing only the 1st method but not all the Methods present in the Class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am automating an application using Selenium WebDriver with Java,TestNG and Maven.
In my test file there are 3 @Test methods,

1. Login
2. Acc_creation (which contains login and Account creation functionality)
3. Cont_creation ( which contains login and Contact creation functionality)

If I execute @Test individually (commenting other methods) all methods are working fine. when I try to run all @Test methods, only 1st @Test is participating in the execution rest all not.
again I changed the priority and run, this time also only one which has the least priority is executing rest all are not in execution part., But Console is showing as all 3 TCs are PASSED .. No error message. Extent report is showing only one TC result. Please help on this.

Same code is executing perfectly in my colleague's machine but not in my system. vice versa I imported his working code into my system and tried to execute. still same issue - only 1st @Test method is executing.

```
@Test (priority =01, description ="Login success", enabled = true, groups = {"Sanity"})
public void TC1_Login() {
    try {
        setCSVFileName("inputfile");//accepts input values from CSV file
        LoginPageModel.login();
        }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   }
 @Test (priority =02, description ="Create a Customer Account", enabled = true, groups = {"Sanity"})
public void TC2_Create_Account() {
    try {
        setCSVFileName("inputfile");//accepts input values from CSV file
        LoginPageModel.login();
        AccountPageModel.newAccountCreate();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Test (priority =03, description ="Create a Contact", enabled = true, groups = {"Sanity"})
public void TC3_Create_Contact() {
    try {
        setCSVFileName("inputfile");//accepts input values from CSV file
        LoginPageModel.login();
        ContactPageModel.newAccountCreate();    
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

`

Comment: are the testng versions same in both the machines?

Comment: @GauthamM, TestNG version is slightly different.
Mine:           7.4.0.202106051955
Colleague's: 7.4.0.202105021622